VBA Word List of Bookmarks with Hyperlinks Comes out on One Line
The following code found on the internet adapted to my purpose gives a List of Bookmarks as links to those bookmarks but many lines empty then all on one line, the last line in the document. I have tried a lot of variants, and managed to get a list of Bookmarks, but without the hyperlinks to those Bookmarks. I can provide the latter on request, but don't want to confuse key the issue that the code refuses to create paragraph breaks between entries.
thanks in advance for any sensible interaction
Chris
Sub Contents1FrmBookmarksWLinks()
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim bookmark As bookmark
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim linkText As String
    ' Create a new section at the end of the document for the bookmark list
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range
    rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    rng.InsertBreak wdPageBreak ' Add a page break to separate from the existing content

    ' Add a title to the new section
    rng.InsertAfter "List of Bookmarks:" ' Title without extra line breaks
    rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    rng.InsertParagraphAfter ' Insert a blank line after the title for clarity
    rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

    ' Loop through all bookmarks in the document
    For Each bookmark In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        ' Get the bookmark name
        linkText = bookmark.Name

        ' Create a clickable hyperlink to the bookmark
        ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add _
            Anchor:=rng, _
            Address:="", _
            SubAddress:=linkText, _
            TextToDisplay:=linkText

        ' Insert a paragraph break after each hyperlink to ensure it appears on a new line
        rng.InsertParagraphAfter
        rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Next bookmark

    MsgBox "Bookmark list with links created."
End Sub


See: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/37272-there-way-summarise-all-bookmarks-cross-references.html

Thanks Shrotter, the layout is better. The link to Sub ListBkMrksAndRefs() is way beyond my coding comprehension but puts out amazing tables loaded with bookmark info, but sadly no links to bookmarks themselves. In the meantime my own tinkering seems to have got a list by converting a couple of the wdCollapseEnd to wdCollapseStart. Only problem is that the list still comes out upside down. New code posted under "Answer own question"

Your code is almost complete. Please give the revised script a try.
Microsoft documentation:

Characters.Last property (Word)


Paragraphs.Last property (Word)

Sub ContentsFrmBookmarksWLinks()
    Dim bookmark As bookmark, linkText As String
    
    With ActiveDocument
        ' Add a page break to separate from the existing content
        .Characters.Last.InsertBreak wdPageBreak

        ' Add a title to the new section
        .Paragraphs.Last.Range.Text = "List of Bookmarks:"

        ' Loop through all bookmarks in the document
        For Each bookmark In .Bookmarks
            .Characters.Last.InsertParagraphAfter
            ' Get the bookmark name
            linkText = bookmark.Name
            ' Create a clickable hyperlink to the bookmark
            .Hyperlinks.Add _
                Anchor:=.Paragraphs.Last.Range, _
                Address:="", _
                SubAddress:=linkText, _
                TextToDisplay:=linkText
        Next bookmark
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Bookmark list with links created."
End Sub





Thanks Taller, this worked really well. I managed to get my original code working by changing         .Paragraphs.Last.Range.Text = "List of Bookmarks:" from "Last" to "First"
However the bookmarks were still coming out in reverse order and stubborn against Sorting using Word Sort Function.
Your code did the trick, already trialled it a few times. But seems complex to get the Bookmark List to land at the top of the document. Tried and gave up, relatively small issue to Cut'n'Paste t the top.
Have a good Christ-mas, Gbu all

Could you clarify whether the list of bookmarks needs to be inserted at the beginning or the end? What is the desired order for the bookmark list?

Adaptation of my code from the link I posted to hyperlink the Bookmark references in the first table:
Sub ListBkMrksAndRefs()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim oBkMrk As Bookmark, StrBkMk As String, StrXREf As String, StrStory As String
Dim Rng As Range, Fld As Field, bHid As Boolean, r As Long
With ActiveDocument
  bHid = .Bookmarks.ShowHidden
  .Bookmarks.ShowHidden = True
  If .Bookmarks.Count > 0 Then
    StrBkMk = vbCr & "Bookmark" & vbTab & "Page" & vbTab & "Line" & vbTab & "Story" & Chr(160) & "Range" & vbTab & "Contents"
    StrXREf = vbCr & "Bookmark Ref" & vbTab & "Page" & vbTab & "Line" & vbTab & "Story" & Chr(160) & "Range" & vbTab & "Type" & vbTab & "Text"
    For Each oBkMrk In .Bookmarks
      Select Case oBkMrk.StoryType
        Case 1: StrStory = "Main text"
        Case 2: StrStory = "Footnotes"
        Case 3: StrStory = "Endnotes"
        Case 4: StrStory = "Comments"
        Case 5: StrStory = "Text frame"
        Case 6: StrStory = "Even pages header"
        Case 7: StrStory = "Primary header"
        Case 8: StrStory = "Even pages footer"
        Case 9: StrStory = "Primary footer"
        Case 10: StrStory = "First page header"
        Case 11: StrStory = "First page footer"
        Case 12: StrStory = "Footnote separator"
        Case 13: StrStory = "Footnote continuation separator"
        Case 14: StrStory = "Footnote continuation notice"
        Case 15: StrStory = "Endnote separator"
        Case 16: StrStory = "Endnote continuation separator"
        Case 17: StrStory = "Endnote continuation notice"
        Case Else: StrStory = "Unknown"
      End Select
      StrBkMk = StrBkMk & vbCr & oBkMrk.Name & vbTab & _
        oBkMrk.Range.Characters.First.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) & vbTab & _
        oBkMrk.Range.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber) & vbTab & StrStory & vbTab & oBkMrk.Range.Text
    Next oBkMrk
    For Each Rng In .StoryRanges
      Select Case Rng.StoryType
        Case 1: StrStory = "Main text"
        Case 2: StrStory = "Footnotes"
        Case 3: StrStory = "Endnotes"
        Case 4: StrStory = "Comments"
        Case 5: StrStory = "Text frame"
        Case 6: StrStory = "Even pages header"
        Case 7: StrStory = "Primary header"
        Case 8: StrStory = "Even pages footer"
        Case 9: StrStory = "Primary footer"
        Case 10: StrStory = "First page header"
        Case 11: StrStory = "First page footer"
        Case 12: StrStory = "Footnote separator"
        Case 13: StrStory = "Footnote continuation separator"
        Case 14: StrStory = "Footnote continuation notice"
        Case 15: StrStory = "Endnote separator"
        Case 16: StrStory = "Endnote continuation separator"
        Case 17: StrStory = "Endnote continuation notice"
        Case Else: StrStory = "Unknown"
      End Select
      For Each Fld In Rng.Fields
        With Fld
          If (.Type = wdFieldRef) Then
            StrXREf = StrXREf & vbCr & Split(Trim(.Code.Text), " ")(1) & vbTab & _
            .Result.Characters.First.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) & vbTab & _
            .Result.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber) & vbTab & StrStory & vbTab & "Ref"
          ElseIf (.Type = wdFieldPageRef) Then
            StrXREf = StrXREf & vbCr & Split(Trim(.Code.Text), " ")(1) & vbTab & _
            .Result.Characters.First.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) & vbTab & _
            .Result.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber) & vbTab & StrStory & vbTab & "PageRef"
          End If
          StrXREf = StrXREf & vbTab & .Result
        End With
      Next
    Next
  Else
    MsgBox "There are no bookmarks in this document", vbExclamation
    GoTo Done
  End If
  Set Rng = .Range.Characters.Last
  With Rng
    .Text = StrBkMk
    .Start = .Start + 1
    .ConvertToTable Separator:=vbTab
    With .Tables(1)
      .AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitContent
      .Columns.Borders.Enable = True
      .Rows.Borders.Enable = True
      .Rows.First.Range.Font.Bold = True
      For r = 2 To .Rows.Count
        Set Rng = .Cell(r, 1).Range: StrBkMk = Split(Rng.Text, vbCr)(0)
        ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Rng, , ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(StrBkMk).Range, StrBkMk, StrBkMk
      Next
    End With
  End With
  Set Rng = .Range.Characters.Last
  With Rng
    .Text = StrXREf
    .Start = .Start + 1
    .ConvertToTable Separator:=vbTab
    With .Tables(1)
      .AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitContent
      .Columns.Borders.Enable = True
      .Rows.Borders.Enable = True
      .Rows.First.Range.Font.Bold = True
    End With
  End With
  .Bookmarks.ShowHidden = bHid
End With
Done:
Set Rng = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Thanks macropod very late here (Sydney), shall look forward to check in morning
